# Comparison the area

Tags: geometry

[image]

Any tricks to solve quickly that which one is bigger: area of DPC or area of DQR?

Comment: Hint: check the bases and height.  Can you now tell the ratio of their areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: They obviously have equal heights. What about bases?